# How can The Flash carry multiple people at once?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

In season 3 in the episode with the gorilla city I'm pretty sure The Flash carries a whole bunch of people at once. We see one bundle of red flashes flowing though the forest and at the end suddenly releasing a flash and 3 or 4 of his companions. If he carried them one by one, we should have seen the bundle of flashes move back and forth several times (once for each person) releasing one at a time.

Also at least in the TV series The Flash does not seem to have special superhuman strength. I can't remember him doing anything like lift or throw heavy objects a normal human could not lift or throw. Hitting someone with super-speed (and heavy impact) is a side effect of his speed ability.

And even if he had superhuman strength, how could he carry more than 2 people (one under each arm) at once?

Was this a writers mistake? Or is it canon that the TV flash has superhuman strength and can carry multiple people at once?

Comment: If you have super strength and speed, you could collect the people in a bundle and as long as they stay between your arms you could move them.

Comment: Depending on the reliability on the arrowikia: http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Barry_Allen#Powers, the CW version of BA does have superhuman strength.

Comment: Note: while the arrowikia says Barry has "superhuman strength", and that he can carry multiple people, it also states that his strength is "peak human", which (to me) doesn't mean superhuman; I would think Green Arrow (to keep it in the Arrowverse) would be his equal, or (outside the Arrowverse) Batman.

Answer (score 5):

In the comics, at least, the Flash has been seen on occasion pulling other people along in his slipstream. While I think he's done this more often as a way to deliver multiple criminals to jail, he's also done it to transport civilians, as seen in [*The Flash* 208](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/The_Flash_Vol_1_208), from August 1971:

[image: Flash transport via slipstream]

(He refers to it as turning into a human twister, but the image definitely shows people simply pulled along in his wake).

I don't think I've seen that in the show (note that I've only watched through season 2, to date). I seem to recall at least one incident during season 2 where we explicitly see the Flash evacuating people one by one, as they start appearing in a parking lot, dropped off by a red blur. I definitely haven't seen the episode, so I'm not sure if that's a possibility based on what's seen.

Comment: This is the last thing I wanted to see today. LOL!

Answer (score 0):

One of the powers that Wally West has had in the comics is to "loan" and "borrow" kinetic energy to objects.  If we assume that TV Barry has a similar power, he could touch a person or object, instantaneously "accelerating" them up to his speed. At that point, inertia would keep the item(s) moving, with only a slight amount of muscle needed to keep them under control.  If he didn't have such a power, attempting to pick up anything at rest is he's traveling at speed would result in his arms being pulled off.